# Get asynchronous value's return on C2

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, construct-2, construct-3

Here is the code I'm using:

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

It returns "0" and then logs in the console the correct result.

But how to directly `return` the result instead of `console.log`?

Some answers have pointed out how to convert it into a Promise.

Comment: return it where? How do you call it? the `exec` runs asynchronously so you'd have to use promises or async/await

Comment: You can't, this it's async.  The value can only be used in the callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, I call it using `Browser.ExecJS("")` in an IDE. It returns "0" for then logging the correct result. It should use a promise to directly return the correct result.

Comment: Nice, @zero298. But how to adapt it to my code? If you answer, I probably will mark it as the correct answer if it works.

Comment: Take a look at this answer in the linked duplicate, it shows how to wrap into a `Promise`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212447/691711  Search for "If the underlying function is not promisified".  This question is asked very often and I'd rather not create yet another duplicate when there is already an answer that solves your issue.

Comment: This is going to depend on exactly what your IDE supports. Your javascript function MUST return before it know the result, so the IDE would need to have a callback mechanism (a way to call from javascript to the IDE), UNLESS it already supports await

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a value from that callback, because it would not be passed to anything. What you can do is defining a Promise that passes the stdout to the resolve method. Here's an example:

```js
    const { exec } = require("child_process");
    function ls() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
                    reject(error.message);
                }
                if (stderr) {
                    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                    reject(stderr);
                }
                console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
                resolve(stdout);
            });
        });
    }
```

What I am doing here is defining a function that creates a new Promise. The Promise will execute your code (the ls -la call), and will fire an exception if there is an error, rejecting the Promise, or it will solve the Promise if everything is fine, passing the stdout value.

You can then use this Promise with something like this:

```
ls().then((out) => {
    console.log(out);
})
```

the out variable will contain your stdout.

If you want some function that returns that value, it should be awaited from this function. An example could be this:

```
async function unwrapLs() {
    const stdout = await ls();
    return stdout;
}
```

Note that you can only call unwrapLs() from inside an async function, because you have to await for its value. In fact, this would be equivalent to calling ls() by awaiting it, but you can only do it from inside an async function.

Comment: It works. But what is missing: it should directly return instead of logging on console. If you update it and it works, it will be the correct answer.

Comment: you could try `Browser.ExecJS("await ls()")` but no way to know it will work

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, it throws a error: "c2runtime.js:16438 Error executing Javascript:  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: `ls().then((out)=>{console.log(out)})` works like a charm BUT shouldn't use console.log (as of the point of this question), but directly return or something alike.

Comment: Returning a value is not the scope of a promise's callback. In fact, my suggestion is to encapsulate the exec() in a promise, so you can use the callback or the async/await mechanism. Returning the value inside the then() will only result in returning a promised value, that will need to be observed, making it needed to use an other .then().

Comment: `const{exec}=require(""child_process"");function ls(){return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{exec(""ls -la"",(error,stdout,stderr)=>{if(error){console.log(`error:${error.message}`);reject(error.message)}if(stderr){console.log(`stderr:${stderr}`);reject(stderr)}console.log(`stdout:${stdout}`);resolve(stdout)})})}ls()` have worked, by just using `ls()` instead of `await ls()` BUT still using the infamous `console.log` instead of directly `return`ing. At least we are getting closer to an answer.

Comment: Again: there is no way to return a value from inside a Promise without having to await for it. It would lead to a useless wrapping of Promises. One other way is to create an async function that awaits the Promise for you, and it could return the value. I'll update the answer with this example

Comment: @GregorioPalamà I'm getting into a solution, but no result yet. I've used the 3 JS quotes of your answer, in the same order; but got no return result. For instance, `function addressbarvalue(){var x=document.getElementById('addressbar').value;return x}addressbarvalue()` returns correctly. How to use the last two quotes of your answer properly? If we get it to work, it means your answer is the correct one

Comment: I've also tried `ls().then((out)=>{console.log(out);return out;})` but it didn't returned.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is that it takes time to run an OS command (perhaps indefinite amount of time).  Javascript will not just halt execution until this is done, so it is run asynchronously.

A value must be returned and must be returned to the caller before it completes. Using promises, the value returned is a promise.

Since you are calling with the Construct 2 Engine which does not have a mechanism for asynchronous calls, you will not get a result directly.

However, Construct 2 engine has a mechanism for calling back into it, using the `Function object`

Your javascript should look like this:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

function ls(callback) {
    exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (c2_callFunction)
            c2_callFunction(callback, [error, stdout, stderr]);
    });
}
ls('lsresult')
```

you can execute like this :

```
Browser.ExecJS("")
```

But, to get the results, you must define a Function  object called 'lsresult', add parameters to the function (error, stdout, stderr) and handle the results there.

Documentation is here: https://www.construct.net/en/construct-2/manuals/construct-2/plugin-reference/function

Comment: Good catch. This is the closest answer. But I got this: "Error executing Javascript:  ReferenceError: ls is not defined". What should be the order of events in the event-sheet?

Comment: yes, I think I see. I think you should execute more like you were doing before.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: caveat is I've never used the construct engine. Just based on the docs.